# Is there a website with text-only (quick downloads) of stock data (symbol, price, etc.)?

Tags: equities, data, market-data

Is there a website that provides a .csv file of every U.S. stock or a text-only web page of U.S. stocks (e.g., symbol, last trading price, price-to-earnings ratio etc.)?  If there is no free one, what is the cheapest subscription price available?

Answer (score 0):

you can download from yahoo finance